# Clicking Login Button goes to 404 Page Not Found (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to check if my login button works by just redirecting or loading another view for my project. However, every time I click the button a "404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found"

I am having a hard time figuring out what to do. I spent almost 2 days just trying to fix this. I tried every solution possible that I could get.

My code for the controller:

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load form helper library
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $this->load->helper('url');
        // // Load form validation library
        // $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // // Load session library
        // $this->load->library('session');

        // // Load database
        // $this->load->model('login_database');
        }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('includes/Login/Login_Header'); //$data);     
        $this->load->view('Login_view');
        $this->load->view('includes/Login/Login_Footer');


    }

     public function login_submit()
    {

        $this->load->view('includes/SFM/SFM_Header'); //$data);
        $this->load->view('includes/SFM/SFM_NavBar');
        $this->load->view('SFM_view');
        $this->load->view('includes/SFM/SFM_Footer');
    }

}
```

My code for the login view:

```
 <body>
<form class="login-form" action="<?=base_url()?>Login_controller/login_submit" method="post">
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-26">
                        Welcome
                    </span>
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-48">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-font"></i>
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid email is: a@b.c">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="Username">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Email"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                        <span class="btn-show-pass">
                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn" ></div>
                            <button class="login100-form-btn">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-115">
                        <span class="txt1">
                            Don’t have an account?
                        </span>

                        <a class="txt2" href="#">
                            Sign Up
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> These errors when index.php is not removed in codeigniter. try this url

1. `action="<?=base_url()?>Login_controller/index.php/login_submit"`

> If you have removed index.php, try this code too.

```
<form class="login-form" action="<?=base_url()?>Login_controller/login_submit" method="post">
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid email is: a@b.c">
    <input class="input100" type="text" name="Username">
    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Email"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
    <span class="btn-show-pass">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
    </span>
    <input class="input100" type="password" name="Password">
    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
</div>

<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
    <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
        <div class="login100-form-bgbtn" ></div>
        <input type="submit" class="login100-form-btn" value="Login">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried the solutions you gave. However, the problem still exists. May I ask where is the "index.php" file located?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue in your URL on form submission.

if you didn't removed index.php from config.php file ($config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
)

Try this

```
<form class="login-form" action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/Login_controller/login_submit" method="post">
```

or you can try this

```
<form class="login-form" action="<?php echo base_url()?>Login_controller/login_submit" method="post">
```

instead of using this

```
<form class="login-form" action="<?=base_url()?>Login_controller/login_submit" method="post">
```

Also check your base_url is proper

Answer (score 0):

## Problem Solved!

The problem was my RewriteBase /FPOOPS was in all caps. When I changed it to /fpoops it now works!

```
   Options -indexes
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /FPOOPS
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</ifModule>

<ifModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</ifModule>
```